# Do any of the PostgreSQL releases for Windows support automatic updates?

Tags: postgresql, update, windows, enterprisedb

PostgreSQL has [two distributions for Windows,](https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/)

- EnterpriseDB
- BigSQL

Do either of these Windows distributions support [automatic updates for the term of support](https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/)? Something that looks for the updates online, downloads them, and installs them.

Comment: The database must be shut down when switching over to the new version. This is not something you'd want to happen automatically.

Comment: @CL. true, even on Ubuntu though. The upgrade has that effect and it still integrates with apt/dpkg.